# Django 2.1 Model Observers

Tags: python, django

Does DJango 2.1 have any support for observers on models?

I've looked into https://github.com/lambdalisue/django-observer, but it appears to only support up to 1.6.

My goal is that everytime a model is updated, I want to fire and command that executes other functions.

Comment: Django has [signals](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/2.1/topics/signals/) that you can use to perform certain tasks when a model is saved to the database. Is that what you mean by "every time a model is updated"?

Comment: @dirkgroten Yes it is, thanks for the direction! if you put that as an answer, I'll mark it as accepted.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Django supports [signals](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/2.1/topics/signals/) that allow you to perform tasks when a model is saved to the database (either before or after it is saved). But also when a model is deleted.

Just implement a handler for one of the built-in signals, as described in the documentation linked above.

If you want to "observe" actual model changes, e.g. when a particular attribute is changed (without the need for saving to the database), then you would need to override the `__setattr__` method of the class.